# Yii2 - Ignore validation if

Tags: php, yii2

In my **Yii2** project, I have related models. Example: A model **Customer** would have an attribute **address_id** that relates to another model **Address**. In the **Customer** model have the **exist validator** that checks that the row exists in the address table.

Typically, on create or update, this validation is ignored if `address = null`. My problem is that sometimes FE would send the `address = 0` indicating the absence of an address.

In this case, I need to not only ignore validation, but to set `address = null`. This can be done **beforeSave** of course, but I'm trying to check if there's some built-in way through which I can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the filter validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#filter) for normalization of an input data. For example:

```
class Customer extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
    {
      return [
          ['address_id', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
              return $value == 0 ? null : $value;
          }],
          // other validators
      ];
    }
}
```